# Ciphertext-Policy Attribute-Based Encryption toolkit "make" error with libgmp

Tags: linux, makefile, cryptoapi

I am getting the following error when trying to "make" the cpabe-0.11 [toolkit/library](http://acsc.cs.utexas.edu/cpabe/) on Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit). All the required libraries, including libgmp, are installed correctly in the system.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libpbc.so: undefined reference to symbol '__gmpz_clear'
/usr/bin/ld: note: '__gmpz_clear' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libgmp.so.3 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/libgmp.so.3: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [cpabe-setup] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I solved this at last. Basically I was getting the error bcz for some reason the libgmp was not linking in the make (that's what the error is saying). But when I checked the Makefile created by running ./configure, it said:-

```
...blah blah blah ...
LDFLAGS = -O3 -Wall \
        -lglib-2.0   \
        -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib -lgmp \
        -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib -lpbc \
        -lbswabe \
        -lcrypto -lcrypto
... blah blah blah ...
```

As you can see, libgmp is mentioned in the LDFLAGS. So much confusion ensued. After a while just on a whim, it tried the following modification to the Makefile:-

```
LDFLAGS = -O3 -Wall \
        -lglib-2.0   \
        -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib -lgmp \
        -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib -lpbc \
        -lbswabe \
        -lcrypto -lcrypto \
        -lgmp
```

So now, for some weird reason it compiles fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved the very same issue I had and for which I have looked around for a day.